# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n 2^{2n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^{2n}}$$

I'd be glad for guidance, because, frankly, I don't have clue here.

Comment: Cannot start with $n=0$

Comment: Does it help any to write it as $\sum\frac1n(\frac14)^n$?  Does the series $\sum\frac{x^n}{n}$ look familiar at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could write this just as well as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}(1/4)^n
$$
Consider the function
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}x^n \quad x \in (-1,1)
$$
noting that $f(0) = 0$.
We evaluate
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} \quad x \in (-1,1)
$$
It follows that
$$
f(4) = f(0) + \int_0^{1/4} f'(t)\,dt = \int_0^{1/4} \frac 1{1-t}\,dt
$$

Comment: You cannot start with $n=0$

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1/4)^n}{n}=-\ln\left(1-\frac14\right)=-\ln\frac34$$

---

Since,
$$\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...$$

Comment: You are off by a negative and that's because the anti derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ has a negative upfront by the chain rule (+1)

Comment: @imranfat edited

Comment: @AlonAlon If you take the geometric series and integrate (The constant turns out to be zero) and then replace x by 1/4, you get ADG's answer

Comment: @imranfat, following your guidance: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^n \, dx  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$. So we have $$\int \frac{1}{1-x} \, dx = -\ln(1-x) $$. Applying $x=4$ we get $-\ln(3/4)$

Comment: Now, I'm not so sure what should be the bounds of those integrals. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Should it stay improper?

Comment: @AlonAlon Nothing with those bounds. You are substituting a value for x since you know that the left hand side and right hand side are the same (w.r.t. interval of convergence) Check out a calculus book chapter Infinite Series

Comment: I will go over this chapter, but as I understand you're implying they are improper. Right?

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^{2n}} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(1/4)^n}{n} = -\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\right) = \log\frac{4}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

For any $z$ such that $|z|<1$ we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{z}x^{n-1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{z}\frac{dx}{1-x} = -\log(1-z) $$
and by plugging in $z=\frac{1}{4}$ it follows that:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n 2^{2n}}=\color{red}{\log 4-\log 3}. $$

Comment: You are able to make the interchange because it's a power-series. Right?

Comment: @AlonAlon: We can exchange $\sum$ and $\int$ since we have uniform convergence due to the fact that $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}=\log{(1-x)}$. The sum of your series is therefore $\log{(4/3)}$